# electronJS: navigator.connection.rtt is always 0

Tags: electron

when executing `navigator.connection.rtt` in the debugger console, this value is always `0`. However calling the same statement in Chromium based browsers returns a variety of values.

Is there anyway to replicate network round trip times in electron, and have this value reflected accurately?

Executing `navigator.connection.rtt` should return a non-zero value when configured:

```
window.webContents.session.enableNetworkEmulation({
  latency: 500,
  downloadThroughput: 6400,
  uploadThroughput: 6400
})
```

[Electron Docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/session#sesenablenetworkemulationoptions)